# Black border appears in camera screen in landscape mode (Unity+Vuforia)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am implementing an AR app.

The AR images are shown correctly when I see the app in portrait mode.
However, the horizontal border appears in the screen when I see the app in landscape mode.
What is happening?

Thank you.

[Screenshots]
Vertical Image
[image: Vertical Image]
Horizontal Image
[image: Horizontal Image]

[Development Environment]

Unity 2019.2.0f1
Vuforia Engine AR 8.3.9
HUAWEI P20 lite(Android)

Comment: some screenshots would be helpful to explain the issue you are having...

Comment: I have not enough reputaion to add screenshot, so I add the link above.  Thank you.